# Can spring Sleuth be used with Scala?

Tags: scala, microservices, trace, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm developing event-driven Microservices which I use Java and Scala. I used Spring Sleuth and Zipkin for request tracing with Java services, can I use Spring Sleuth with Scala? if not how can I generate trace id and span id in Scala to be sent to Zipkin.

Answer (score -1):

I have no knowledge of it being impossible. Maybe you should first try doing it and then asking a question? Also, if for some reason it turns out you can't use it, then if you just google `zipkin scala` you'll see things like https://github.com/lloydmeta/zipkin-futures , https://github.com/bizreach/play-zipkin-tracing etc.